# ARM FunctionApp listkeys retrieve previous custom key

Tags: azure-resource-manager, cicd, azure-deployment

We've got ARM deployment template which is working fine, the only issue there is, as we're creating FunctionApp and adding custom key to it that will be referenced in API Management to connect API with FunctionApp backend. It looks like, even with `dependsOn` in backend resource in template referencing to `FunctionKeys` resource, `listkeys()` still fetches one from before deployment. Has anyone faced this scenario and is there anything in particular I'm missing? Or is `dependsOn` thinking that the key has been deployed already, and even tho future deployments update the key, backend isn't actually waiting for the completion of `FunctionKeys` resource deployment?

Template snippets:

`backends`

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends",
  "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('apiManagementServiceName'), '/', variables('functionName'))]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apiManagementServiceName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys', variables('functionName'),'default','apimanagement')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "url": "[concat('https://', variables('functionName'), '.azurewebsites.net/api')]",
    "protocol": "http",
    "resourceId": "[concat('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionName'))]",
    "credentials": {
      "header": {
        "x-functions-key": [
          "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionAppId'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys.apimanagement]"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`functionKeys`

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[concat(variables('functionName'), '/default/apimanagement')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "apimanagement"
  }
},
```

Comment: Are you expecting the function key to be regenerated ? I imagine that if the key already exists it won't be changed.

Comment: You could specify a different value to see if that work for you: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites/functions/keys?tabs=bicep.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, this might be an actual thing, I'm yet to test it in a pipeline run, so far I was deploying it via Azure Deploy Custom Template and it was regenerating a key every time, but maybe during the deployment (incremental) via pipeline it won't be regenerated?

Answer (score 0):

The `listKeys` call is scheduled too early... In a greenfield scenario the deployment would fail, in brownfield you "get the old key" instead of the new one.  It's a "limitation" in the template engine that you can work around.  Basically, you need to nest the deployment that uses the listKeys function (i.e. your backend resource).  There's a little bit of detail on it [here](https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/) in the **Use a Nested Deployment** section

Comment: When testing this out recently - using a nested deploy to delay the call the ListKeys to grab access keys from a storage account, i found that i got the wrong keys. They appear to be keys from either a previous incarnation of the stoage account, or something else entirely. In the end, i had to grab the keys using the Get-AzStorageAccountKey cmdlet, and update appsettings connection strings with it as an extra step. Too bad the ARM Template didn't work, as now our ARM template isn't usable for a full deploy by itself any longer.

Comment: If you have a repro of the nested deployment returning the old keys, I'd love to see it so we can improve...

Comment: @bmoore-msft Thanks for more insights, I wouldn't agree that in a greenfield scenario this will fail and `listkeys` is scheduled too early, as we've tested afterwards and it works fine, the issue is brownfield scenario as you've described, which I'm yet to test the deployment with Release Pipeline. Thanks for the link to the article, nesting templates is in the roadmap so will help a lot!

Comment: I would agree with przeciag. Seems like deploying over the top of an old storage account (though it has been deleted - even hours ago) that is the issue with Listkeys calls. I will try to create a basic repro of it when i have downtime at work. Will reply here when i have it. (Or if i can't reproduce it!)